# Swift Parse MapView Not Displaying CalloutAccessory and Segueing

Tags: swift, parse-platform, mkmapview

I currently have a UIMapView with different annotations pinned for the different locations of users on the map. I'm trying to segue to the respective users profile when the annotation is clicked. Here's my code to set up the annotations:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "location")

query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

    if let brandsLocation = objects {

        for object in brandsLocation {

            if let brandLocation = object as? PFObject {

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                let annotationPoint = object["geoPoint"] as! PFGeoPoint

                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annotationPoint.latitude, annotationPoint.longitude)

                annotation.title = brandLocation["annotationTitle"] as? String

                annotation.subtitle = brandLocation["annotationSubtitle"] as? String

                self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I believe the segue is supposed to happen, however it isn't doing anything for some reason.

```
// When user taps on the disclosure button you can perform a segue to navigate to another view controller
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, 
                 calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView{

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToUserProfile", sender: view)

        print(view.annotation?.title) // annotation's title

        print(view.annotation?.subtitle) // annotation's subttitle

        //Perform a segue here to navigate to another viewcontroller
        // On tapping the disclosure button you will get here
    }
}


// Here we add disclosure button inside annotation window
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    print("viewForannotation")
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if pinView == nil {
        //println("Pinview was nil")
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
    }

    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure) as UIButton // button with info sign in it

    pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button

    return pinView
}
```

I'd like for the segue to happen when the annotation is clicked or double clicked, and then perform a segue to that new view controller while sending the specific username info as well. I'm pretty sure I'll be able to send the user info but I just need to figure out how to make the segue happen. I think it may have to do with the fact that in the new XCode update my `calloutaccessory` hasn't been showing. Here's a screenshot from my app. [MapView Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm4e7.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `didSelect` method instead of `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToUserProfile", sender: view)
    print(view.annotation?.title) // annotation's title
    print(view.annotation?.subtitle) // annotation's subttitle
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't even register that I selected the annotation or mapview